# Pull from my fork

Tags: git, github

I have a fork on GitHub. I received a pull request, next I approved it and now I want to pull the updated files to my disc. How I can do it? I tried 'git pull', but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you referring to [this pull request](https://github.com/daroPL/amu_automata_2011/pull/1)? If so, it seems it's been properly merged and cloning the repository shows the change, so a pull should work. Are you sure you're on the right branch?

Comment: Yes, I have only one branch - master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably you want to `git fetch` and then either rebase your local changes on top of it or merge them into your local branch.

Comment: Hmmm... it doesn't give any output. The files haven't been updated.

Comment: I typed 'git fetch' in the git console.

Comment: It doesn't update your files, it fetches ref from the repository. Then you either `git merge origin/master` (or whatever your ref is) or `git rebase origin/master` (or whatever your ref is). But be sure you *know* what's happening. Especially if you go for rebase.

Comment: 'git merge origin/master' works after the 'git fetch' statement. Thanks!